# not a function error when trying to push onto and array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This has me a little puzzled on because it truly seems I am doing this correctly. The:

```
 submit()
```

function is working and I confirmed by printing out in the console. However I am getting an error saying:

[image: Error]

index.html

```
<form ng-click="submit()" ng-controller="enterNameController">

        Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter a new name." />
              <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" />

    {{name}}

</form>

  <div ng-controller="enterNameController">
    {{name.length}}
      <ul ng-repeat="n in name">
          {{n}}
      </ul>

  </div>
```

enterNameController.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('enterNameController',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.name = [];
        $scope.submit = function(){

            if ($scope.name){
                $scope.name.push($scope.name);
                $scope.name = '';
                console.log("Inside submit function")
            }
        }

    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('enterNameController',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.list = [];

        $scope.submit = function(){
            if($scope.list){
                $scope.list.push($scope.name);
                $scope.name = '';
            }

        };

    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a $scope.name like array in your controller and $scope.name like model in the view... You must rename the array ;)